# jquery .each misses the first row

Tags: jquery

I have the following in a page the var rows shows length=1 but then it reaches the .each statement it doesn't enter it. I must be missing something. I only have this problem when there is only 1 row in the table. Any thoughts?

```
$('.addnewrow').click(function() {
        var rows = $('#webgrid tr:gt(0)');
        rows.each(function (index) {
           // do something 
        });

       // now do something else based on the results of the .each
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)** takes index which is `0` based and here you are asking for everything greater than the first element. So when there is only row you don't have any other tr's after the first one so the statement `$('#webgrid tr:gt(0)')` returns empty collection.

Comment: ahh that makes sense. My table has a header row that will always be visible and a tbody that will contain the data rows. how can I skip the header to ensure I only retrive the collection of tbody rows. I tried only selecting the tbody but I encountered the same behavior

Comment: @Tim You mean you think what you are doing is the right selection? Can you replicate in a fiddle? As far as i know the definition of gt, it works that way..

Comment: @Tim Do `$('#webgrid tbody tr')` Should work, Can you put it in a fiddle otherwise?

Comment: it should be inserting a new row below A identified as B but it never enters the .each to identify the first row as A

Comment: @Tim In the fiddle when i click on addrow it inserts the row below the previous one, that is what yuo are doing also.

Comment: I tried the $('#webgrid tbody tr').each() and it too jumped over the iteration of the rows.

Comment: yes but the first column should indicate that it's row B. and it comes in undefined. The intent is to maintain an alphebitical order in the grid as rows are added and or deleted. So if A,B,C,D are in the grid and the user deletes B then they are forced to reuse B when adding a new row. This works well when the row count is greater than 1.

Comment: @Tim I am now completely confused :( Your original question and your current issue seems completely different.

Comment: it's the same issue, when I have 1 row in a tbody the .each does not iterate. If it stepped into the .each it would identify the next char to use to set up the new row.

Comment: Now I'm completely confused. I put an alert in the .each and it executed but firefox developr tools does not step into the code. This may be a debugger issue and not a jquery issue. Thanks for your help. I guess it was moot but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

In `#webgrid tr:gt(0)`, you are selecting every `tr` which has the ancestor `#webgrid` AND is in a index position GREATER THAN 0 (`gt(0)`), in this case, using the `:gt()` pseudo selector is useless if you want to iterate through all the `tr`. Since `gt(0)` means "every element that is at a index above 0" and you only have one element at position 0, you are missing it alltogether.

Hope this helps!